# How to unsubscribe RxJs observer when unmounting?

Tags: reactjs, rxjs

I have a redux action observer function, that makes a call to the backend. and if it fails/error, it keeps retrying infinitely. Now what I wanted to do is to kill/unsubscribe the observer when un-mounting.

Here is snippet of my code...

```
.pipe(
    switchMap(() => fetchData()),
    retry({delay: 1000}),
    catchError(() => triggerErrorActionType())
)
```

Is there a way to have it skip **retry** or unsubscribe when un-mounting? or any other work around?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have a subject called finalised$

```
finalised$ = new Subject<void>();
```

Put a takeUntil in your chain

```
.pipe(
  switchMap(() => fetchData()),
  retry({delay: 1000}),
  catchError(() => triggerErrorActionType()),
  takeUntil(finalised$)
)
```

and then on unmount make the subject emit.

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  this.finalised$.next();
  this.finalised$.complete();
}
```